Проблема с загрузкой файла в safari
Всем привет, у меня появилась проблема при тестировании сайта на mac
При загрузке одного и того же файла он не дает его загрузить второй раз, на винде все работает
Загружаю его первый раз и отправляю на сервер - все работает

Пытаюсь загрузить такой же файл еще раз, но ничего не происходит, все также пусто, ошибок в консоли нет

Вот код с методами vue
    sendMessage() {
      this.$emit("new-message", {
        version: this.getAIVersion,
        chat: this.getActiveChat,
        message: this.getTrimMessage,
        file: this.file,
        username: this.getUsername,
        type_data: typeData,
      });

      this.message = "";
      this.file = null;
    },
    uploadFile(e) {
      const file = e.currentTarget.files[0];

      this.file = file;
    }


возможно проблема не на фронте а на беке)

@pyduti, не, вряд-ли, я же не отправляю никаких запросов, когда загружаю файл, метод uploadFile - хэндлер для события change у input, то есть мне просто второй раз не дает загрузить один и тот же файл

тут извиняюсь, не правильно понял ваш вопрос, возможно вам поможет такая реализация
  const file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
  this.file = file;
  e.target.value = null;   // Сброс значения input поля
}

В чем суть я думаю что для safari загрузка такого же (дубль) файла не является ивентом и в конце загрузки файла мы обнуляем поле input для того чтобы он не считал этот файл дублем (сам использую windows не могу проверить)

@pyduti, сработало, спасибо, можете оформлять как ответ

Решил данную проблему, изменив метод uploadFile:
uploadFile(e) {
   const file = e.currentTarget.files[0];

   this.file = file;

   e.target.value = null; // добавил это
}

